# How do I create a function common to all the pages in ASP.net?

Tags: asp.net, function, menu

I'm making a website that has a menu on all the pages that needs to be changed frequently. Right now I'm copying the code of the menu in all the pages, and so, if the menu needs to be changed, I have to open each page and change the menu there.

Is there any way by which I could define a function in a file somewhere that just writes the menu code using Response.Write() and then keep calling that function on all the pages that need the menu? That way whenever I'd need to make changes to the menu, I'll only make it in the function definition.

Comment: Do you know about Master Page ????

Comment: Use [Master Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtxbf3hh.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Master page is the perfect candidate.

Add the menu in master page.

You can also create a user control for this.

But if you want a function for doing a common task through out the site then create a class

and add the function is that class. Create an object of that class and call the function

anywhere in the site.

Comment: Marking answer because of the extra advice about the class. Needed it. And yes, master pages seems like the right choice.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at a [user control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y6wb1a0e.aspx) or [master pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtxbf3hh.aspx). Be more elaborate, so we can help you better.

Comment: I'll look into both. And that's as elaborate as I can get. I have many pages, and menu on all pages needs to be the same. Right now I'm developing the site, so I keep editing the menu code very often.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you should consider using a [user control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y6wb1a0e.aspx) for the menu.

Comment: Master Page is a valid option as well depending on his application structure.

Answer (score 1):

If you define a Menu in your Master Page it should refelect in all child pages.

All you need to do is create a Master Page and define your Menu in that.

After that you should create your child page using option >> WebForm using MasterPage

Apart from that for any other functions which are in Master page you can call them in your child page like this:

You can call method inside a MasterPage like this:

```
var master = Master as MyMasterPage;
if (master != null)
{
   master.Method();
}
```